# Lucene.net 3.0.3 not working

Tags: asp.net, lucene.net

Im using VS2010 and lucene.net lib 3.0.3 for integrating the search functionality in my asp.net project. When I write

```
Lucene.Net.Store.Directory directory = 
    Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.Open(directoryPath);
```

Intellisense is saying:

> 'Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory' does not contain a definition for
>   'Open'

Why the lucene.net 3.0.3 is still reading the depricated methods.
I learned that `GetDirectory()`  method is depricated from [this website of Apache.](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/core/deprecated-list.html)

Any solution please?

Comment: You're reading old api docs,  you're linking to 2.9.4. Stuff deprecated back then may be removed already in 3.0.3.

Comment: Hi Simon, Could you please share the link to download the 3.* version dll of lucene.net.

Comment: grab it from NuGet - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try get directory method. Or please check if you have any  as far my knowledge that, this directory open method was in previous lucene versions.

```
FSDirectory objDirectory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(pstrDatabase_path);
Analyzer Analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
IndexWriter Writer = new IndexWriter(objDirectory, Analyzer);
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Field("FIELD_NAME", "FIELD_VALUE" , Field.Store.YES, 
Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
Writer.AddDocument(doc);
Writer.Commit();
Writer.Close();
```

Comment: Hi Vic, thanks for the input but I'm not getting why my VS is considering the deprecated version of Lucene.net.

Comment: Try this remove current reference and add new lucene reference ad a DLL. Not project.